# How to optimize Viewport for video editing on low-spec hardware?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, optimization

I downloaded blender in hopes of using it for simple video editing, and while it appears to have all the tools I want, trying to preview the video is simply not working well enough. The preview is struggling to get anywhere past around 1.5 fps. When I checked in task manager to try and find the bottleneck, nothing showed higher than 50% usage...

Unusable preview framerates is something i'm quite accustomed to with my computer, but i was hoping there might be a way to manage a smooth playthrough of something close enough to video that i can time cuts and transistions.

Comment: Creating proxies it's usually the way to go in this kind of issue. Is there anyting that is preventting you from taking advantage of them?

Comment: Other than knowing litterally nothing about proxies, i don't think so

Comment: Have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZl1xS9Lmvw and see if that helps. You can also refer to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32203/how-do-i-use-proxies-in-the-vse-correctly

Comment: There are a number of ways to optimize the playback performance of the VSE here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/155675/37272